# "Design your app for tablets" Optimization tip

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, tablet

I've recently uploaded an app in google play. I have only one png icon which I've
 put on m, h, xh, xxh ,xxxh dpi folders, the rest of the app icons are svg's and I've put them in the anydpi folder. Yet in the console I see the following optimization tip:

```
Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:

Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities.
```

Here's a screenshot of my res folder

[image]

I've search stackoverflow and found some related questions but there was no answer that helped me. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add this config line to your gradle file:

`defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

Comment: My project's min sdk is 21, is it still needed? if yes why

Comment: Yes - this is telling the system to use the SupportLib capabilities.  The docs clearly state you need this anyway (if you read the Google docs about using Vector graphics)

Comment: I added it but the tip is still there